# Triple-Boot Windows 8.1 (main OS on drive), Windows 10 Preview VHD, and Linux (VHD) - NO CD/DVD/USB

Tags: linux, windows-8, boot, multi-boot, vhd

TL;DR Possible to Multi-Boot a main Windows 8.1 installed on drive, Windows 10 Preview VHD, and Linux, preferably retaining the Windows 8.1 graphical Bootloader?

I have Windows 8.1, installed Windows 10 Preview to a VHD, and added that VHD to the Windows graphical bcd bootloader. So now when I boot up, I have the option for Windows 8.1 or the Windows 10 Preview VHD.
I used this guide to accomplish that: (http://blogs.technet.com/b/haroldwong/archive/2012/08/18/how-to-create-windows-8-vhd-for-boot-to-vhd-using-simple-easy-to-follow-steps.aspx)

I want to also multi-boot Linux, but I have no CD/DVD/USB. So I found this project VMLite (http://www.vmlite.com/) which is not actively updated at this moment. But they offer pre-made Linux VHDs for download. They also offer a program to enable what I'm trying to do (I think through some sort of virtualization or messing with RUB/Windows boot loader) but it doesn't seem to be working with Win8.1.

So, I can mount the Mint VHD I downloaded from there to Windows Disk Manager, but it doesnt assign it a drive letter. So I downloaded ext2fsd (Windows ext Driver), and it was able to read the VHD I mounted through the Windows Disk Manager, and assign it a drive letter. I then used EasyBCD to add that drive letter to the Boot loader. Now I get the option when I boot up, but it fails to start, saying there was a "windows" error.

I assume it's because this boot loader can't boot Linux (Maybe even just the [vista]/Win7/8/8.1 bootloader). Or because the ext2/3 driver isn't initialized at the bootloader. Or because what I'm trying to do is just impossible and/or stupid.

I'm essentially trying to make a ghetto Wubi scenario that works with Win 8.1

I'd be willing to change bootloaders, but want to retain my Windows 8.1 main install and Windows 10 VHD as options to boot into alongside a Linux install.

Can I maybe partition my Win 8.1 install, boot Linux in a VM, and install it from the VM onto that partition, and then maybe have an option from the GRUB loader saying Linux and Windows Boot Loader, where if I choose WBL I can then choose Win 8.1 and Win 10.

Maybe adding a Win XP VHD boot, then installing Wubi from there.

If this is possible without any external media please let me know any options!

TL;DR Possible to Multi-Boot a main Windows 8.1 installed on drive, Windows 10 Preview VHD, and Linux, preferably retaining the Windows 8.1 graphical Bootloader?

P.S. I have a laptop that had Win8 installed by default (not upgraded) with the UEFI BIOS so I can't access BIOS settings without getting into Win8 first apparently.

Comment: TL;DR. If I recall correctly vBoot by VMlite is MBR/BIOS only.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer can run Hyper-V you can create easily a virtual machine
(select second generation VM and Linux ISO as source - this will create UEFI installation).

Here you have Native boot of Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 (from VHD).
In Windows 8.1 you can run Linux as guest OS in Hyper-V.

Other virtualization machines for Windows are available - VirtualBox, VMware.

You should consider attaching at least a USB drive to your machine as this extends computer's capabilities. I would always keep on external media at least:

1. Recovery USB for every OS I have installed.
2. Installation USB for every OS I have installed.
3. Regularly backup my user files to external USB drive in case of total disk failure !

If you install natively (to separate partitions) every OS you would achieve the best performance for every OS. Installations to VHD (native boot) have only small overhead for disk access.
Installations in VM are usually slow in performance as processor and disk are virtualized.

You can use [Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net) to examine Windows 7/8 boot configuration data (BIOS and UEFI).